# Есть ли отличия в присвании функции в python с использованием lambda и без нее?

Tags: python, lambda

Чем отличаются эти две строки?

```
function1 = lambda x: function2(x)
function1 = function2
```

В частности, в учебнике Тарика Рашида по написанию нейронных сетей предлагается следующий вариант описания активационной функции

```
self.activation = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)
```

Comment: Ну, в первом случае вы создаёте новую функцию

Comment: А function2 это что? Если у function2 два обязательных аргумента, то function1 из первой строки вообще не будет работать

Comment: @andreymal, function2 имеет 1 аргумент

Comment: А завтра появится второй, и первый вариант в итоге сломается. Ну или наоборот второй. Всё зависит от того, где, как и зачем вы это всё используете

Comment: Функция `scipy.special.expit` может принимать два аргумента, хотя в документации это в явном виде не указано (а при большом желании даже три, но третий будет уже именованным, а не позиционным)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Об этом очень много везде написано. И все сводится к тому, что функции в `python` - это объекты первого порядке. Для нас важно, что функции - это объекты (как практически все в python), то есть, помимо определения функции как такового, к ней можно обратиться по ссылке (`reference`).

В вашем случае:

```
function1 = lambda x: function2(x)
```

Эквивалентно определению новой функции через оператор `def`:

```
def function1(x):
    return function2(x)
```

То есть, вы создаете новую функцию с помощью `inline`-функции `lambda`. Не смотря на то, что это в общем-то, рабочий пример, его не рекомендуют использовать для эксплицитного (явного) определения функции по очевидным причинам.

Во втором случае:

```
function1 = function2
```

вы как бы создаете ярлык на  `function2` с именем `function1`, обращаясь к последней по ссылке (`reference`). При этом, фактически, `function1` вызывает `function2` и и возвращает полученный от нее результат.

Подобная система работы `by reference` с функциями в `python` позволяет довольно гибко с ними обходиться. Например (Dan Bader):

```
>>> def myfunc(a, b):
        return a + b
>>> funcs = [myfunc]
>>> funcs[0]
<function myfunc at 0x107012230>
>>> funcs[0](2, 3)
5
```